# Calculated Field Data Studio Invalid formula - Invalid input expression. - Failed to parse CASE statement

Tags: looker-studio, calculated-field

Any thoughts why this is happening?

```
CASE 
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Event Label,'Registrate ahora')
THEN 'Registrate ahora'
ELSE REGEXP_REPLACE(Event Label,'.*:','')
END
```

Error:

```
Invalid formula - Invalid input expression. - Failed to parse CASE statement.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parsing error is most likely caused by CASE WHEN not accepting your REGEXP_REPLACE function as valid

> ELSE ...

"result".

It's perhaps not very clear from the [help](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724?hl=en), but the "result" (the value to return by THEN / ELSE) **can only be** a **dimension**, **metric**, or **literal value**.

Considering you need something more dynamic, the workaround is to use an extra calculated field - e.g. named "Event_Exp". For this field you can then use

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(Event Label,'.*:','')
```

as calculation formula.

Your previous CASE WHEN expressions then becomes

```
CASE 
 WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Event Label,'Registrate ahora')
  THEN 'Registrate ahora'
 ELSE Event_Exp
END
```

While not intuitive for people used to the power of CASE WHEN in SQL, it should satisfy the restrictions Google Data Studio has and worked for me in a similar scenario.

---

In case this suggestion should not solve your issue, it could also be related to a more general bug which Google Data Studio has regarding the translation of regular expressions into correct operators for database queries. We had to develop workarounds for all regular expressions being used in conjunction with the PostgreSQL connector and the Google fix is still outstanding.

The [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=REGEXP) provides an overview about anything waiting for a fix + possible workarounds for some cases.